# ASP.NET's equivalent of PHP's $_GET and $_POST?

Tags: asp.net

As thet title says.

I'm new to asp.net, and I'm sorta trying to build some AJAX-stuff to learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[ASP.Net AJAX](http://www.asp.net/ajax/) may also be worth reading as there are some built-in things that could be useful.

["Request.QueryString"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524784.aspx) and ["Request.Form"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985.aspx) are the likely answers to the title question.

Comment: I ended up just using the `QueryString` to get the parameter. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Following up with marr75's response, the [Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.request.aspx) property exposes a dictionary of GETed and POSTed variables.

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swe97x0b.aspx.

It explains how to access the response and request context.  If you're going to do ajax stuff, you might want to think about WCF REST, in which case, it's totally different and I would recommend going through some tutorials to see how the http elements of the application are abstracted away.  In any event, in a lot of ASP.NET development, you don't touch the response and request contexts directly.

Comment: in addition to WCF REST, i'd recommend looking at ADO.NET Data Services and ASP.NET AJAX framework

Answer (score 0):

`Request` object is a map of all the request headers - both from the POST request and URL encoded params:

```
//This will retrieve the value of "SomeHeader" from the request
//e.g. http://localhost/page.aspx?SomeHeader=thisisvalue
string value = HttpContext.Current.Request["SomeHeader"];
//value == "thisisvalue"
```